# Undefined index: clear laravel 8 con oracle 10g

Tags: laravel, oracle, laravel-8, oracle-10g

Agregué a mi proyecto los roles y permisos con Spatie. Al querer migrarlo me comenzó a tirar error de tablas con nombres demasiado largos ya que oracle permite 30 caracteres solamente. Cambié manualmente esto y ya no me tira error de eso pero me dice lo que puse en el título.

El cartel es el siguiente:

> ErrorException
> Undefined index: clear
> at C:\Users\pasros02.CAJA\Desktop\aseguradoras\database\migrations\2022_03_09_111604_create_permission_tables.php:57
> 53▕         Schema::create($tableNames['model_has_permissions'], function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableNames, $columnNames, $teams) {
> 54▕             $table->unsignedBigInteger(PermissionRegistrar::$pivotPermission);
> 55▕
> 56▕             $table->string('model_type');
> ➜  57▕             $table->unsignedBigInteger($columnNames['clear']);
> 58▕             $table->index([$columnNames['model_morph_key'], 'model_type'], 'id_model_type_index');
> 59▕
> 61▕                 ->references('id')

Comment: ¿Llegaste a hacer la migración y/o intentaste migrar de vuelta? Si querés _hacer rollback_ a la migración, podés revisar la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations).

Comment: Hola, sii. Intente migrarlo pero el error siempre aparece ahi. Hasta intente con fresh y refresh pero no hay caso!